# rSocket websocket postman testing mime types and endpoints

Tags: websocket, postman, rsocket, spring-rsocket

I am using `spring-boot-starter-webflux` and `spring-boot-starter-rsocket` version `2.7.1`

The rSocket transport is set to `websocket` like this:

```
spring.rsocket.server.transport=websocket
spring.rsocket.server.mapping-path=/rsocket

# this setting has no effect when transport==WEBSOCKET
spring.rsocket.server.port=7000
```

There's a spring `@Controller` endpoint `@MessageMapping` setup for a simple `string` like:

```
@MessageMapping("test")
String test() {
        Logs.Info("*** Received test ***");
        return "tested";
}
```

I want to get a successful test done with Postman. Run the spring boot app locally and connect to `ws://localhost:7000` using mime types

```
dataMimeType: 'application/json'
metadataMimeType: 'message/x.rsocket.routing.v0'
```

Like this:

[image: mime types]

The rsocket websocket connects, but I can't hit the endpoint `test`

[image: test]

With error `1005 No Status Received: Missing status code even though one was expected`

[image: error]

On the server the error is

```
DEBUG [reactor-http-nio-2] debug: [c4e97d34-1, L:/127.0.0.1:7000 - R:/127.0.0.1:2051] Cancelling Websocket inbound. Closing Websocket
DEBUG [reactor-http-nio-2] debug: [c4e97d34, L:/127.0.0.1:7000 - R:/127.0.0.1:2051] Removed handler: PongHandler, pipeline: DefaultChannelPipeline{(wsencoder = io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocket13FrameEncoder), (wsdecoder = io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocket13FrameDecoder), (reactor.right.reactiveBridge = reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler)}
DEBUG [reactor-http-nio-2] debug: [c4e97d34, L:/127.0.0.1:7000 ! R:/127.0.0.1:2051] An outbound error could not be processed
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoErrorSupplied.call(MonoErrorSupplied.java:61)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:228)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onComplete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:203)
at reactor.core.publisher.SinkEmptyMulticast$VoidInner.complete(SinkEmptyMulticast.java:238)
at reactor.core.publisher.SinkEmptyMulticast.tryEmitEmpty(SinkEmptyMulticast.java:70)
at reactor.core.publisher.SinkEmptySerialized.tryEmitEmpty(SinkEmptySerialized.java:46)
```

What's the incorrect setting in Postman?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is don't use postman. Rsocket is a binary protocol, Even though based on Websocket, There are many tools test it.

- use `spring message` write a unit test

```java
@Autowired
private RSocketRequester rSocketRequester;

StepVerifier.create(rSocketRequester
                        .route("test")
                        .retrieveMono(String.class))
                .expectNext("tested")
                .verifyComplete();
```

- [RSocket Client CLI (RSC)](https://github.com/making/rsc)

```bash
rsc --request --route=test --debug ws://localhost:7000/rsocket
```

Comment: Hi, per the other answer there was a way to get the postman to push data to the rSocket endpoint, but it requires a `SETUP` frame first. I've asked another question on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73109641/send-rsocket-setup-frame-using-postman)

Answer (score 0):

Actually the following `message` was received:

```
{
    "data":"test",
    "metadata":4
}
```

Per screenshot

[image: test]

But now the error on the server side is:

```
DEBUG [reactor-http-nio-6] lambda$receive$0: receiving -> 
Frame => Stream ID: 2064452128 Type: REQUEST_N Flags: 0b100000 Length: 42 
RequestN: 539124833
Data:

DEBUG [reactor-http-nio-6] sendErrorAndClose: sending -> InvalidSetupException: SETUP or RESUME frame must be received before any others
```